# Send notifications to users that app is being discontinued

Tags: ios, notifications

I'm having to get a very quick intro to iOS development to support apps for my organization. We would like to post a notification to users of one of our apps that it is being replaced by another. I suppose this would look like a banner when the app is launched.

What is the right method to make this happen? It's not a push notification (doesn't look like we are enabled for that anyway) but it sounds like it would still require an update to the app. Can anyone help?

Comment: My god, someone asking how to do this well when the app store is full of the most jarring, glaring notifications within apps! Just having a slightly less than full screen notice appear - oner with a visible close or action button would be great! With of course a link to the new app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd address this question to StackOverflow.com. Basically you'll need to create a UIAlert or a UIAlertController and yes, you will need an update to the app.